# How to remove labels from a MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am trying to make a satellite view (via a MapView) without labels. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "label" you are referring to placename labels (e.g., towns, buildings), there is no API in Android to disable those AFAICT.

Comment: Thanks for response. I mean roadway, street name, avenue ... etc.

Comment: Same thing -- AFAIK, those are baked into the tiles themselves downloaded from Google, so they cannot readily be turned off, at least on Android.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again. Happy new year coming.

Comment: For anyone else interested in this feature, I've added a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22405

Answer (score 3):

There's always the option of using a `WebView` with the [JavaScript Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/). There are a number of upsides to this approach, one of them being the ability to use satellite tiles without labels.

[This article on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html) describes the basics for this approach and mentions more pros/cons.